# How to use update_batch using Codeigniter arrays?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just want to ask how can I perform a batch_update using arrays in CodeIgniter Here's my sample code:

Controller:

```
function flightsaleseditdata()
{
    if ($this->session->userdata(travelsec . 'Login_Id'))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('inv_passuserid', 'trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('inv_passname[]', 'trim');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            $result['status']  = 'error';
            $result['message'] = validation_errors();
        } else {
                $inv_passuserid = $this->input->post("inv_passuserid");
                $inv_passname = $this->input->post("inv_passname");
                $inv_passuserid = $this->Flightsales_model->flightsaleseditdata($inv_passuserid,$inv_passname);
                    if ($inv_passuserid > 0) {
                    $result['status']       = 'success';
                    $result['message']      = "<script> swal({title: 'Updated Successfully',icon: 'success'})</script>";
                    $result['redirect_url'] = 'flightlist';
            } else
               $result['message'] = "<script> swal({title: 'Email Address Already Exists',icon: 'error'})</script>";
        }
        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
        $this->output->set_output(json_encode($result));
        $string = $this->output->get_output();
        echo $string;
        exit();
    }
else
        redirect('administrator');
}
```

Model:

```
public function flightsaleseditdata()
{
    $inv_id=$this->input->post("inv_id");
    $inv_passuserid = $this->input->post("inv_passuserid");
    $inv_passname = $this->input->post("inv_passname");
    $query =$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `flight_user` WHERE inv_id='$inv_id' ");
    if($query->num_rows())  
    {

            // Flight Passenger
            $query =$this->db->query("select * from `flight_user` where `inv_id`='$inv_id'");
            $row = $query->row();
            $invid=$row->inv_id;
            $username=$row->inv_userid;

            for($i = 0; $i < count($inv_passid); $i++){

             $updateArray = array(
                'inv_pid' => $invid,
                'inv_passuserid' => $username,
                'inv_passname' => $inv_passname[$i]);

             $this->db->where('inv_pid', $invid)->update_batch('flight_passenger', $updateArray);
            }
    }
    return  $inv_id;    
}
```

View:

```
<form id="FlightSalesEditForm" role="form">
            <div class="col m6 s12">

            <div id="html-validations" class="card card-tabs">
                <div class="card-content">
                    <div id="html-view-validations">
                        <div class="row">
                            <input class="validate" id="inv_id" value="<?php echo $invoicedetails['inv_id']; ?>" name="inv_id" type="text">
                            <table id="dynamic_field">
                                <?php for($i=0;$i<sizeof($passengerdetails);$i++) { ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><label for="">Name</label>
                                    <input class="validate" id="inv_passname<?php echo $i+1; ?>" name="inv_passname<?php echo $i+1; ?>[]" value="<?php echo $passengerdetails[$i]['inv_passname']; ?>" type="text"></td></tr>
                                <?php } ?>
                              </table>
                            <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <span id="FlightErrEdit_error"></span>
                                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light right" type="submit">Submit<i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

Script:

$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#FlightSalesEditForm").submit(function(e)
            { 
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#FlightErrEdit_error").html('Please Wait......');
                $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "/flightsaleseditdata",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),success: function(response)
                    {
                        alert(data);
                        var result=JSON.parse(response);
                        $('#FlightErrEdit_error').html(result['message']);
                        $('#FlightErrEdit_error').show();
                        window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},2000)
                    }
                });
            });
        });

Updated Code
 That's my code And I can't figured it out where's my error. I also checked my array values and there's no error in my array. My problem is I can't update my table using batch_update.

Comment: what exactly is happening? blank page? have you tried enabling db_debug in database.php? how exactly are you submitting the form, ajax? i don't see a form tag anywhere

Comment: Yes i m using ajax to form submit.

Comment: i also asked a few other questions that were pertinent; please try and answer them all by editing your question as doing so in comments isn't the easiest for others to read. now that you have identified that you are using ajax, I will tak on another question: do you have any console errors and have you checked the response in dev tools when you submit the form?

Comment: Hi @Alex I have updated my code.i didn't tried enabling db_debug

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '0 = Array WHERE `inv_passid` IS NULL' at line 1

UPDATE `flight_passenger` SET 0 = Array WHERE `inv_passid` IS NULL

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/travel-portal/system/database/DB_driver.php

Comment: ok now we are getting somewhere. do you see: `$inv_passid` in your model function? should it be `$inv_passuserid`? im surprised you aren't getting a notice/error as inv_passid doesn't exist. do you have error reporting enabled?